# Always query by a lower case value for a specific field

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I have the class as below:

```
class TranslationDictionary(Document):
    src_text = StringField(required=True)
    dst_text = StringField(required=True)
    src_lang = StringField(required=True)
    dst_lang = StringField(required=True)
```

In this class I have a couple of query methods, some of them are filtering by src_text, e.g.:

```
@classmethod
    def translation_exists(cls, src_lang, src_text):
        return bool(cls.objects(src_lang=src_lang, src_text=src_text).first())
```

The problem I want to solve is that I want always to search by src_text lowercase value. Of course I could update all methods and change condition to `src_text=src_text.lower()` but that's not a really good solution for me. I read about [mongoengine custom query sets](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#custom-querysets) and that would be some solution but it requires (at least I didn't find a cleaner way to do it) to override `__call__` method:

```
class TranslationDictionaryQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def __call__(self, q_obj=None, class_check=True, slave_okay=False,
                 read_preference=None, **query):
        # Make sure we always query for the lowercase src_text value
        if 'src_text' in query:
            query['src_text'] = query['src_text'].lower()
        return super(TranslationDictionaryQuery, self).__call__(
            q_obj=None, class_check=True, slave_okay=False,
            read_preference=None, **query)
```

So the question is - does anyone know a better/cleaner solution that will convert `src_text` value to lowercase always, when using `TranslationDictionary.objects`?